# Is there any way to know how many users are currently online at a given time?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, users

Usually I find that maximum traffic occurs on this site around (8:00 pm to 4:00 am, as per [Indian Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) (IST, UTC+05:30)), but I don't have any concrete data related to it. So

- Is there a way to find out how many people are currently online on Physics.SE?

---

I ask this because when I get ask question I take care that it is uploaded in the given time interval so that it can get the maximum response from the fellow users.

Comment: Quite frankly, I find to strange to postpone an answer because you're waiting for an "optimal" time to post it.  Why not just write a good answer when you have the time and post it when you are done?

Comment: @Jmac for no I give the answers immediately which I can give with my knowledge though I was asking for question response time (i.e., if I ask a question then how probable it is to be answered as sometimes some good question go down 4th he list and get neglected.).

Comment: @JMac OP is looking for when to ask questions, rather than answer them.